# Design Choice: how to wrap up large files with 100k+ vectors

Tags: python, performance, oop

I am comparing design choice of wrapping either each "vector" into Object, or each whole "matrix" of vectors into Object.

I realize there will be more overhead if I try to wrap up each path by a class object, but it would make the system a lot easier to understand and implement.
However, I thought this might cost us the performance.

What would be a convention when it comes to loading big data as attributes?
I appreciate your thoughts in advance,

q

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to "wrap paths" and store many attributes for those paths, and there are lots of "paths".

Instead of defining classes that require lots of custom objects creation just for the paths themselves, store the paths (strings I suppose) as keys in a `dict`, and the attributes in any appropriate form inside.